# discord.py-rewrite - Difference between close() and logout() methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So, to close the connection to `discord`, there are two methods:

- [`close()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.close)
- [`logout()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logout)

According to [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#), [`logout()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logout) is:

> Just an alias to [`close()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.close). If you want to do extraneous cleanup when subclassing, it is suggested to override [`close()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.close) instead.

What is *"extraneous cleanup when subclassing"*? What is the difference between these two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no real difference between `close()` and `logout()`. Logout() is just an alias for close().

You could in theory use them interchangably but it's better to stay consistent. Personally, I've always used close, didn't even know Logout() existed. You're fine to use whichever you please.

[As you can see here, `logout()` literally just calls `close()`.](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/client.py#L434-L445)